Did "imeds" bus exist?
Yesterday I see a very funny "informatic-action" movie called New World Disorder, at minute 15 I see this image

The speed 10gb/s is a little fast for pci bus, but they also specify "imeds"
what is "imed" bus? Searching on google return me a porn scene description.

This is entirely unrelated and explains nothing. @elbarna Please un-accept.

If it didn't exist, this is probably better answered on [movies.se].

Reading the screenshot, it looks like semi-believable technobabble.

This would be closed on Movies & TV under their Identification of Trivia custom close reason.

I am 100% sure that it is a term invented for the movie. Computer hokum in movies is a thing, and there is a web site, 'TV Tropes' that has a section devoted to the subject:

"Quite exciting, this computer magic." — Viv, This is Spın̈al Tap
Computers on TV often bear only superficial resemblance to their real
life counterparts.

Magical Computer (TV Tropes)

This does not appear provide any enlightenment whatsoever. Can you explain how mathematical modeling of vehicle transit systems and their fuel supply (“integrated thermal/electrical/natural-gas multi-energy distribution systems”) in 2022 has any relation to a computer PCI expansion bus in 1999? It looks like you just Googled “imeds bus” and posted the first hit with no analysis.

Did you even read the link?  Economic models have nothing to do with computer busses.

I cannot delete the answer because it was accepted, but I was able to edit!

"I believe this is made up because many other things are made up" doesn't seem like an answer founded on much.

OK, Dave, why don't you write an answer?
